# Problem with SqlConnection, ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the following C# code:

```
public string TargetDate()
{
    SqlConnection con = 
        new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Timer;Trusted_Connectopn=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Timer");
    con.Open(); 

    DataSet ds = new DataSet(cmd,con); 
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
    da.Fill(ds); 
    con.Close(); 
}
```

but I get error at the: `new DataSet(cmd,con); ...`

> the error: CS1502: The best overloaded
>   method match for
>
> ```
> 'System.Data.DataSet.DataSet(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
> ```
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'
>   has some invalid arguments

What is could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, the connection string should be "Server=localhost;Database=Timer;Trusted_Connection=True". Thanks.

Comment: You can also try the documentation on MSDN, [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection
    ("Server=localhost;Database=Timer;Trusted_Connection=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Timer", con);

con.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);

con.Close();
```

This is even better:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Timer;Trusted_Connection=True"))
using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "select * from Timer";
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    dataTable.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: does using `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` in `ExecuteReader` make a difference ?

Comment: Plus: **fix the typo** `Trusted_Connection=True` instead of `Trusted_Connectopn=True`

Comment: +1 for the `using.......` blocks! And even better yet: don't use `SELECT *` but explicitly specify the columns that you really need...

Answer (score 4):

You've got the wrong constructor for the DataSet. Try this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(con);
```

Comment: Is there a SqlDataAdapter constructor that takes SqlCommand and SqlConnection?

Comment: @Alex: Ah I see, I confused the string "selectCommandText" with the SqlCommand object. You are right.

Comment: Wow 3 upvotes for something inconsistent ! i believe you should clarify that cmd is a `string` and not a `command` object

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mixed up the constructors:

Try the following:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(con);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there a SqlDataAdapter constructor that takes SqlCommand and SqlConnection?